# How to pass and apply blur function to specific input on parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'am using a custom input field as a separated component. I add more than one input field in parent component via directive(s): `<app-input ...></app-input>`

I want to pass the blur event/function to parent component for specific input (in this case password field), to get its value and check this value based on Reg Expression.

I have been searching quite long (also here on SO) and tried really couple of options, but none of them did give the expected clean behavior.

I keep getting the following error:

> el => undefined

I think the point is how to pass the exact element Ref to `form.component.html` so that the function can be applied on the exact specific input field which is `password` in this case.

I'am using `Angular: 5.2.10`

**input.component.html:**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>
        <mat-icon matPrefix>lock</mat-icon>
        <span>{{ inputLabel }}</span>
    </mat-label>
    <input matInput type="{{inputType}}" name="{{inputName}}" [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange)="modelChange.next($event)" required="{{required}}" pattern="{{regEx}}" (blur)="onFieldBlurClient('name.value')">
    <mat-error align="end">
        {{ inputError }}
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**input.component.ts:**

```
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {

    public parentFormGroup: FormGroup;

    @Output() onFieldBlur: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Input('label') inputLabel: string;
    @Input('name') inputName: string;
    @Input('validationError') inputError: string;
    @Input('type') inputType: string;
    @Input('pattern') regEx: string;
    @Input() required = true;

    @Input() model: any;
    @Output() modelChange = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onFieldBlurClient(el) {
        this.onFieldBlur.emit(true);
    }

}
```

**form.component.html:**

```
<app-input [label]="'Password'" 
           [type]="'password'" [name]="'password'" 
           [validationError]="'Pass is not valid'" 
           [required]="true" 
           [parentFormGroup]="form" 
           [pattern]="(password_rexExp)" (onFieldBlur)="onBlur()"> . 
</app-input>
```

**form.component.ts:**

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    ....
    public password_regExp
    public toogleRegExCheck = false;
    ...

    constructor() {
        this.password_regExp = '......';
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    public onBlur(el) {
        console.log(`el => ${el}`);
        if (!password_regExp.test(el)) {
           this.toogleRegExCheck = true; 
        } else {
           this.toogleRegExCheck = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the `Event`

```
 (onFieldBlur)="onBlur($event)"> .
```

Comment: Good one. Just I forgot clarify that I want to get the value to validate it again the regEx. So, in this case when I apps `$event` and log the value as `console.log(`el => ${el.value}`);`,  I get `undefined` Your suggestion, gives me `true` in log.

Comment: that because you are emitting a boolean value here `this.onFieldBlur.emit(true);` emit an object with a `value` property then it will work.

Comment: Oh, you're right. My bad. What would it be then exactly? : `this.onFieldBlur.emit();`

Comment: If you don't mind, I would ask how to pass an elementRef for the input to `form.component`. as you can see, I pass name, required (true/false), label etc. dynamically. One thing I would like to add: elemRef is e.g: `#inputPass`. So That I can dynamically add a reference to the specific input via `<app-input ...></app-input>`. For instance: `<app-input ...[eleRef]="#xxxxx"></app-input>`. Am I in the right way?

Comment: Following your hint, here is how it works now: this.onFieldBlur.emit( (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value );

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the $event in your template in the function call, in order to get the current item's value.

```
<app-input [label]="'Password'" 
       [type]="'password'" [name]="'password'" 
       [validationError]="'Pass is not valid'" 
       [required]="true" 
       [parentFormGroup]="form" 
       [pattern]="(password_rexExp)" (onFieldBlur)="onBlur($event)"> .
```